# SQL Select Query Timing Out

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, timeout

I have a table in my SQL Server 2008 database called **dbo.app_additional_info** which contains approximately 130,000 records. Below shows the structure of the table.

[image]

When I run a query like the one below in SQL Server Management Studio 2008

```
select app_additional_text
from app_additional_info
where application_id = 2665 --Could be any ID here
```

My query takes a long time to execute (up to 5minutes) and sometimes it times out. This database is also connected to a Web Application and when it runs the above query, I always get a timeout error.

Is there anything I can do to speed up the performance of my query?

Your help with this would be greatly appreciated as this is grinding my web application to a halt.

Thanks.

**Update**

Below shows my execution plan from SSMS (I apologise for poor quality)

[image]
[image]

Comment: @podiluska There is a Foreign Key relationship on it, does that count as an Index?

Comment: @tgriffiths Since you're using SSMS, go to `Query -> Include Actual Execution Plan` to see whether your query is using an index. In fact, if you can post your execution plan, we can help you even more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the limited info in the question, it looks like you are doing a table scan because there is no index on application_id.  So, try this:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_app_additional_info_application_id on 
                app_additional_info (application_id)
```

your query should run much faster now.

Comment: `Clustered Index Scan` says it all: "SCAN" every row.  this index should make it say "seek"